# How to add a column to IEnumerable list using linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

In my Controller Constructor I initialise my IEnumerable list which I will be passing it as model to my Views.

```
IEnumerable<classB> mdata;

public MyController()
{
   DataContext context = new DataContext(//connectionstring code missing//);
   mdata = context.GetTable<classB>().ToArray();
}
```

In my Action now I want to "add" a column to the mdata from a var list I retrieve from a Session as below:

```
var list = (List<Tuple<int,int>>)Session["ids"];
```

The list above contains id & Level both type int. The "id" will be used to match the rows in mdata which also have column "id". So once it finds a match it should add "Level" to the IEnumerable list. So far I have:

```
mdata = mdata.Where(x => list[].Item1.Contains(x.Id)); //not working
```

Comment: How do you want to add a column in a strongly typed class? What is `classB`? and  you cannot access `list[]` in `x => list[].Item1..` like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change your ClassB definition (add/remove properties at runtime) - Level property should exist there. But you can join both sequences by id and then select new anonymous object which will have level and joined ClassB instance:

```
var query = from b in mdata
            join t in list on b.Id equals t.Item1
            select new {
               B = b,
               Level = t.Item2
            };
```

Updating `Level` property in ClassB:

```
foreach(var pair in query)
   pair.B.Level = pair.Level;
```

---

Another option (you will avoid anonymous objects creation):

```
var levels = list.ToDictionary(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);
foreach(var b in mdata)
{
    int level;
    if (levels.TryGetValue(b.Id, out level))
        b.Level = level;
}
```

Comment: If I add Level property to mdata can i update it - they can only be level 0 - 3. so can i update the property each time. Is this possible ???

Comment: @user2906420 yes, it is possible - after getting matched pairs you can enumerate results and update mdata

Comment: Sergey I want to use second option with toDictionary because I want to update column in mdata - however gives an error because my Item1-ID can have duplicate values - how can i overcome this ???

Comment: @user2906420 if you have duplicate tuples, then `var levels = list.Distinct().ToDictionary(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);` - because Tuple has build in GetHashCode and Equals implementation

Comment: Sergey it does not work error: "An item with the same key has already been added.".  my code is:                                  `var list = (List<Foo>)Session["list"];  //retrieving different controller  
var levels = list.Distinct().ToDictionary(t => t.Id, t => t.Level); //error here`

Comment: @user2906420 there is no `Id` and `Level` property on `Tuple<int,int>`. Are you sure you are converting correct list to dictionary?

Comment: Yes Sergey I am NOT using Tuple I am using class Foo:     `var list = (List<Foo>)Session["list"];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46769/discussion-between-user2906420-and-sergey-berezovskiy)